# Convert uiview to uiimage before its displayed

Tags: swift, google-maps

I'm trying to add a UIView to google maps at a particular coordinate, from what I can see the easiest way to do this is to convert it to an image and add it as a `GMSMarker`. I've found a nice extension that convert the view to an image for me:

```
extension UIImage {
    convenience init(view: UIView) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.isOpaque, 0.0)
        view.drawHierarchy(in: view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        self.init(cgImage: (image?.cgImage)!)
    }
}
```

The issue is that the view has not been rendered yet and therefore its frame is zero. The view contains text that will vary in length on initialization only so I cant give it a set frame.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension works nicely (tested it), so it is all about the calling after it has rendered. Try viewDidAppear or calling it in a function after rendering has occurred.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    newImageView.image = UIImage(view: self.topView)
}
```

If that does not work, can you share your code calling the extension?

Comment: This was my issue, i was testing my implementation and calling it in the init of the view controller as opposed to more realistically after the view had loaded and the api request had come back successfully. Thank you

Comment: @Wazza, if this helps, would appreciate choosing this as a solution. Thanks.

Comment: sorry completely forgot, too excited about implementing

Comment: Not a problem! Best of luck!